# google api v3 blogger post insert php ajax

Tags: php, google-api

I have tried to get blogger blog info by using the api.

```
    $blogger = new Google_BloggerService($client);
$data = $blogger->blogs->getByUrl(array('url'=>'http://puwaruwa.blogspot.com/'));
```

and it worked fine and gave me the details.

then I tried to insert a post as below

```
    <?php

$token = json_decode($token, true); //already got the token

?>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/55555555555555/posts/",
                Authorization: "OAuth <?php echo $token['access_token']; ?>",
                data: {"kind": "blogger#post",
              "blog": {
                "id": "555555555555555"
              },
              "title": "A new post",
              "content": "With <b>exciting</b> content..."},
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success:function(data){alert(data);}
                });

</script>
```

but it gives me

```
    {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

please help me to insert a post to blogger blog through api v3 using php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simple than I was trying to post on blogger. I am presenting here only the php code that does the post and it was working fine for me.

```
$blogger = new Google_BloggerService($client);    
$mypost = new Google_Post();
$mypost->setTitle('this is a test 1 title');
$mypost->setContent('this is a test 1 content');
$data = $blogger->posts->insert('5555555555555555555', $mypost);
```

thanks.

full detailed posting is at 
http://gayanonline.blogspot.com/2013/03/google-api-v3-with-php-using-blogger.html

Comment: How to add tags/labels to the post ?

Comment: Using this code with current version of google api client is not working. Any sugestions?